# Android: Activity not launching when clicking widget

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I have a widget whose layout has two buttons. My code follows,

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {

    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
    PendingIntent pendingLayout = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);


    Intent searchIntent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
    PendingIntent searchPendingLayout = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, searchIntent, 0);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.searchwidget);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetbutton, pendingLayout);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetsearch, searchPendingLayout);

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context,
            RecentTaskWidget.class.getName());

    mgr.updateAppWidget(comp, views);
}
```

The widgetbutton and the widgetsearch are the two views in the layout. I am getting the corresponding views from the remoteviews object and adding the pending layout to each of them. However, the activities are not starting. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Thx!

Comment: Do you get any error?For example `no activity found` or ...?

Comment: no error... nothing's happens

Answer (score 0):

Override `onUpdate()` method of your `AppWidgetProvider` and add this code  to it's body:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
    PendingIntent pendingLayout = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    Intent searchIntent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
    PendingIntent searchPendingLayout = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, searchIntent, 0);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.searchwidget);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetbutton, pendingLayout);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetsearch, searchPendingLayout);
    ...
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
}
```

You can see [this page](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Moved the code to onUpdate() like you said... but its still not working. The code looks fine to me. Not sure why the intent is failing

Comment: @rahul do you add my smple cod?I changed last line,and I hope this help you.